# How to convert tuple to a multi nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple in the following format:

```
(639283, 298290710, 1385)
(639283, 298290712, 1389)
(639283, 298290715, 1395)
(745310, 470212995, 2061)
(745310, 470213821, 3713)
(745310, 470215360, 6791)
(745310, 470215361, 6793)
(745310, 470215363, 6797)
(911045, 374330803, 4905)
(911045, 374330804, 4907)
(911045, 374330807, 4913)
(911045, 374330808, 4915)
(911045, 374330809, 4917)
```

I want to convert into a nested dictionary like this:

```
{639283:{298290710:1385, 298290712:1389, 298290715:1395},745310:{470212995:2061,470213821:3713}............}
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing this? It seems pretty simple, but i can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use tuple unpacking combined with [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make your life easier.

Create an outer `defaultdict` with `dict` as its default value. Then, you can simply loop through your list of tuples once, setting the values appropriately as you go.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict) # dict where the default values are dicts.
for a, b, c in list_of_tuples: # Each tuple is "key1, key2, value"
    d[a][b] = c
```

Of course, you presumably know more about what these values actually represent, so you can give your dictionary, and the individual items, better, more descriptive names than `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

Comment: I think both response are great, but this seems rather intuitive and clean. So, I am accepting this :)

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the tuples based on the first item, and then iterate over those groups in a dict-comprehension to get the desired result.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> d = {k: dict(x[1:] for x in g) for k, g in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))}
>>> pprint(d)
{639283: {298290710: 1385, 298290712: 1389, 298290715: 1395},
 745310: {470212995: 2061,
          470213821: 3713,
          470215360: 6791,
          470215361: 6793,
          470215363: 6797},
 911045: {374330803: 4905,
          374330804: 4907,
          374330807: 4913,
          374330808: 4915,
          374330809: 4917}}
```

Where `data` is your list of tuples or tuple of tuples.